# How can I bulk public permissions for everyone none?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket with about 800 videos in. I need to bulk edit so that the public permissions for the "everyone" group does NOT have read or write permissions for object access.

I would also like to know how to make sure that all future videos automatically are set this way. I am trying to **prevent** someone from being able to copy and paste the link to a video into a new browser window and being able to watch it.

[image: s3 screenshot]

Here is the current bucket policy I have setup:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "HTTP referrer policy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketnamehere/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://www.example.com/*",
                    "https://www.example.com/*",
                    "http://example.com/*",
                    "https://example.com/*",
                    "http://dev.example.com/*",
                    "https://dev.example.com/*"
                ]
            },
            "Null": {
                "aws:Referer": "false"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this policy?  As written, it seems to allow any download with any Referer set, because `"Null": { "aws:Referer": "false" }` is true if *any* referer is present.  That seems somewhat the opposite of your intention.

Comment: By default, objects in S3 are *not* accessible. Are you saying that your objects current have READ set to True? If so, then this is being set by your process that uploads your objects to Amazon S3. You should fix that first and then set about fixing the current situation. Please note that a Bucket Policy does not change the READ setting, but can override it.